# Ngrok reconnecting (failed to fetch CRL. errors encountered: asn1: structure error: length too large)

Tags: node.js, ngrok

I can't run ngrok successfully, I'm using a node.js app with the command

```
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port', 3000);
});
```

but yet everytime I start ngrok using `ngrok http 3000`, it just show up these error messages

```
reconnecting (failed to fetch CRL. errors encountered: asn1: structure error: length too large) 
reconnecting (jsonHTTP.Lookup: No such host: tunnel.ngrok.com)
reconnecting (resolved tunnel.ngrok.com has no records)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to describe how did I solve this issue :
Apparently there was some sort of blocking on my dns provider either due to my network provider or my country generally.
I was able to connect to ngrok & It was solved when I used (not promoting any products here) **Cloudflare warp**.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the exact same error.
The problem for me was the internet connection - ngrok requires a stable connection, as soon as I changed the wifi network the problem was solved